# How to print HTML characters without iteration(append) in Flask-SocketIO?

Tags: python, jquery, flask, flask-socketio

I have prepared a basic Flask Socket IO as part of learning.

```
socket.on('time_update', function (results){
            const total_time = results.time1;
            const a = Math.round(total_time)
            $('#time1').css('width', a)
            $('#log').append($('<h4/>').text(total_time).html());
        })
<h4 id="log"> Time Elapsed #' </h4>
```

For the `id="log"`, I see the `total_time` value keeps iterating in the single lines.
I just need the constant value to be updated. so i need the replacement of append if any.

Reference output image : [image: 1]

I need the value to be constantly updated as a single integer and not line by line. Is there a method other than append to achieve it?

Comment: from what I understand you can directly use `html` itself like `$('#log').html(\`<h4>${total_time}</h4>\`)`

Comment: It helped to my need. Thanks Sumit